# how to copy all the numbers of richtextbox in the ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I searched the internet a lot for doing this but found no way to do it.
if these numbers are in the `richtextbox1`

```
1
2
3
4
....
```

how to copy all the numbers of `richtextbox1` in the `ListBox1`?

Comment: `richtextbox1.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}).ToList().ForEach(n => ListBox1.Items.Add(n))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(RichTextBox1.Lines)
End Sub
```

[image: RichTextBox Data to ListBox]

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much <3